# How to rotate pins relative to the west?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maps

I have pins on the map. How can I rotate these pins relative to the west?
I tried to rotate the pins with the SetRotation () command, but the pins rotate relative to the parent element. And when you turn the card, the pins do not rotate. So I need to turn the pins relative to the west

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            string[] words = pin.Address.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Type.ToString());
            if (words[0] != "my")
            {
                if (words[0] == "Red")

                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.red));
                else marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.white));
            }
            RotatePinWithAngle(marker, words[1]);
            return marker;
        }
        void RotatePinWithAngle(MarkerOptions marker, string angle)
        {
            switch (angle)
            {
                case "left":
                    { 
                        marker.SetRotation(0);
                        break;
                    }
                case "up":
                    {
                        marker.SetRotation(90);
                        break;
                    }
                case "right":
                    {
                        marker.SetRotation(180);
                        break;
                    }
                case "down":
                    {
                        marker.SetRotation(270);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I use CustomMap and this fragment of code show my try to rotate cars icon.
Its working, but icons rotate relative to the parent container and when I rotate map, icons dont rotate

[image]

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate the map and keep your icon do not move.
For rotating the map.  you could use this [Google Maps API](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps).It is support to bearing

```
  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(
                new CameraPosition(
                     new Position(35.71d, 139.81d), // center
                     17d, // zoom
                     45d, // bearing(rotation)
                     60d)), // tilt
                     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

[Here is my demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiQt01tgkNAyLtMcb-rGE_SRcm__-42r/view?usp=sharing).If you want to test it, please replace the `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyA2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxByV1jK5Lzdo" />
```

Comment: Yes, but what is this icon ? I use this icon and rotate it on the road, but if I rotate the map, this pin does not rotate with the map and the icon does not stay on the road.I edit question and add icon

Comment: If you rotate the map, the icon is always static like this GIF.https://imgur.com/a/Xi64hbO , if the icon rotate the with map rotating, it seems you do not move, I am confused about it.